# using grep or any of its variations

Tags: grep

Write a regular expression to match a proper IP address. IP address has this format: x.x.x.x ,
where x is any number in the range of 0 to 255.

e.g.
192.168.0.1

10.100.0.3

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/106179 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/10006459

Answer (score 3, accepted):

extended regular expression:

```
grep -Eo '\b(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b'
```

Comment: what does mean \b(?:(?:25))

Comment: In regular expressions, \b anchors the regex at a word boundary or the position between a word and a non-word character, or vice versa.